# What PipeWire Combine Stream module combine.mode's values mean?

Tags: multimedia, pipewire

According to official PipeWire [Combine Stream](https://docs.pipewire.org/page_module_combine_stream.html) docs `combine.mode = capture | playback | sink | source, default sink`; what `capture | playback | sink | source` mean? please post links to their docs (if any), thank you.